# Exclude entry from glossary?

Tags: latex, glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package in LaTeX.  I've got `\gls{foo}` in my document, but I don't want the entry for "foo" to appear in the glossary.  How can I keep a working (i.e. expanding) `\gls{foo}` in the body of my document, but exclude the entry for "foo" from the glossary?

EDIT: I want to use `\gls{foo}` to indicate "as used here, 'foo' has its specific meaning within this document."  In a few cases, though, I've ended up with a "foo" whose definition is too obvious--or difficult--to articulate in the glossary.

So I want `\gls{foo}` to be expanded as usual, but I don't want the "foo" entry to appear in the glossary.

I hope this adds a little more information about what I'm trying to accomplish.  It may be an abuse of glossaries, but I find it helpful to make sure I'm always using the same words and the right words while writing technical documents.

Comment: Can you give an example of where this would be useful?  Why not just replace `\gls{foo}` with `foo`?  What is the actual end-effect you'd like to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `glossaries` package you can create an "ignored" glossary like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[glignoredl]{ignored}{glignored}{glignoredin}{Ignored Glossary}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foofoo}{name={FOOFOO},description={foofoo stuff}}
\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={FOO},type={ignored},description={no good description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={BAR},description={bar of stuff}}

\begin{document}

Here is a \gls{foo} that is also a \gls{bar}, but of course it's also a \gls{foofoo}.
Why not consider buying a \gls{foo}?

\printglossary
% \printglossary[type={ignored}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but the following should work:

```
\let\oldgls\gls% store the original meaning of \gls in a new command named \oldgls
\let\gls\relax$ make \gls do nothing
Some text with \gls{foo} no links to the glossary, 
and no ``foo'' entry in the glossary.
\let\gls\oldgls% restore the original meaning of \gls
Some more text with \gls{bar} that links to the glossary,
and with a ``bar'' entry in the glossary.
```

Comment: `\gls{foo}` appears, say, dozens of times all over my document.  Also, sometimes "foo" was a different word, but has since become "foo" and now I don't want "foo" in the glossary, but I do still want it referred to with `\gls{foo}` (it might be changed itself at some point in the future).

Therefore I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require me to adulterate every usage of `\gls{foo}`.

I'm thinking there should be some way to set the entry as if it were "unused" by the time _something_ gets around to generating the glossary.  I don't mind adding something like `\glsignore{foo}` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by adding the terms to a special `common` dictionary. It's actually a built-in feature of the `glossaries` package and it's even [exemplified by the package author](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-ignored.tex). From said example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newignoredglossary{common}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{commonex}{type=common,name={common term}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}. \gls{commonex}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `\newignoredglossary` command.